# High to Low poly Texture Baking

Tags: texture-baking

I am trying to bake diffuse textures from high-poly to low-poly model and it gives me black result.

I did successfully bake textures using this method before, but this time none of my models work. I am at the end of my wits, please let me know what am I not seeing here?

Low poly model is uv-unwrapped.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ykFWOvt5lQGeZ9y_sKdHTvC4s-ZRdpCv/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

Put the *Metallic* value of the *Principled BSDF* at 0, you can't bake the diffuse of a material with metallic.